# ComboBox en DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Trabajo en una app Windows Forms en el cual tengo un control DataGridView en el cual una de sus columnas es de tipo Combobox puedo poblar de datos el ComboBox sin ningún problema.

El problema que tengo es que necesito que el primer elemento que contiene el Combobox este seleccionado en este caso es `<<Seleccione>>` no he podido conseguirlo a primera vista no se ve nada en el ComboBox hasta que se haga click para poder desplegar el ComboBox y poder seleccionar los items.

De esta manera cargo el ComboBox

```
public IEnumerable<UniversalExtend> SelectList(Expression<Func<UnidadMedida, UniversalExtend>> source)
    {
        return _unidadMedidaRepository.SelectList(source);
    }

    public IEnumerable<UniversalExtend> ListaUnidadMedidas
        (Expression<Func<UnidadMedida, UniversalExtend>> source)
    {
        var listaItem = SelectList(source).ToList();
        listaItem.Insert(0, new UniversalExtend() { Id = -1, Descripcion = "<<<Seleccione>>>" });
        return listaItem;
    }
```

Persistencia

```
public IEnumerable<UniversalExtend> SelectList(Expression<Func<T, UniversalExtend>> source)
    {
        using (var context = new BusinessContext())
        {
            var result = context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking()
                .Select(source).ToList();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Enlazando los datos al ComboBox

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cboColMedida = dataGridView1.Columns["colCombo"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
        cboColMedida.DataSource =
            _saUnidadMedida.ListaUnidadMedidas(
                x => new UniversalExtend() {Id = x.UnidadMedidaId, Descripcion = x.Abreviacion}).ToList();
        cboColMedida.DisplayMember = "Descripcion";
        cboColMedida.ValueMember = "Id";
```

De esta manera es como se muestra cuando el cbo ya esta cargado de datos.
[image: ComboBox]

Comment: y poniendo el selectedvalue al primer item, o selecteditem al primer item no funciona?, porque eso se haria si el combo ya tuviera un valor, le pasarias el mismo...

Comment: Me puedes mostrar un poco mas de código para ver si puedo replicar tu caso, de esta manera podría ayudarte mas facilmente.

Comment: @Ivan-San ¿Que es lo que necesitas, como traigo los datos de la db?

Comment: Si algo mas para poder recrearlo en mi maquina y ver de que manera se comporta el código que muestras

Comment: @Ivan-San lo voy a agregar

Comment: También puedes hacer una consulta de selección `SELECT` en el cual traes código/valor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He estado jugando con tu código y la respuesta es bastante simple basta con asignarle un valor a la celda del combobox (En tu ejemplo darle el valor -1 que declaraste en el Id) justo después de enlazar los datos con tu combobox.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["colCombo"].Value =-1;
```

Es decir en la parte del código donde asignas el DataSource quedaría así:

```
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cboColMedida = dataGridView1.Columns["colCombo"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
    cboColMedida.DataSource =
            _saUnidadMedida.ListaUnidadMedidas(
                x => new UniversalExtend() {Id = x.UnidadMedidaId, Descripcion = x.Abreviacion}).ToList();
    cboColMedida.DisplayMember = "Descripcion";
    cboColMedida.ValueMember = "Id";
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["colCombo"].Value =-1;
    dataGridView1.RowsAdded += DataGridView1OnRowsAdded;
```

Y la función que realizará la selección cada vez que se añada una nueva fila quedaría:

```
private void DataGridView1OnRowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["colCombo"].Value = -1;
    }
```

Espero que te pueda solverntar el problema.

Un saludo

Comment: Si funciona, pero cuando agrego la siguiente fila ya no toma ningún valor en el value, porque me imagino que no esta en el `rows[0]`

Comment: Claro, deberías darle valor después de agregarla cuando te salte el evento de creación

Comment: Completo la solución con el evento

Comment: Muchas gracias soluciono el problema que deseaba.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tu necesitas es capturar el valor nulo por defecto de la columna en el combobox:

```
cboColMedida.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "<<<Seleccione>>>";
```

Esto despues de haber terminado de llenar los datos al *DataGridViewComboBoxColumn*

Comment: Hola pero ese item lo agrego por código es mas ya lo traigo cuando hago el select solo esta para establecerlo por código, pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Entonces quitalo del codigo y deja el defaultcellstyle con eso deberias de cumplir tu objetivo